# How do I stop setNeedsDisplayInRect / drawRect coalescence?

Tags: iphone

When programming my app, I get to the point where I have to update two rectangles on the screen.  So I call [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:rect1] and then [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:rect2].  When my drawRect method is called, the rectangle parameter is the smallest rectangle which contains both rect1 and rect2.

I can handle this with no problem, but when the two rectangles are far apart, then I am updating a lot of real estate with no gain.  In this case, I would just like to repaint my two small rectangles.

So my question is how can I prevent the underlying system from coalescing my two calls into one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to prevent the system from coalescing the calls because in `-drawRect:`, you can query the individual regions that have to be updated by calling `-getRectsBeingDrawn:count:`. This will return your individual rectangles `rect1` and `rect2`.

Note that `-getRectsBeingDrawn:count:` is guaranteed to return non-overlapping rectangles. This seems to imply that if, for example, you called `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:` twice for the same rectangle, `-getRectsBeingDrawn:count:` would only return that rectangle once. In other words, you don't need to worry that you're drawing the same region twice.

Comment: I don't see how to go from a UIView to an NSView.  What is the linkage there?

Comment: @No One in Particular: You can't -- `UIView` is the iOS (or rather UIKit) equivalent to Mac OS's (or rather AppKit's) `NSView`. And unfortunately, `UIView` doesn't seem to have `-getRectsBeingDrawn:count:`...

Comment: Although answered in the negative, it is the most informative one.  I will accept this one since no-one has a better idea.  Thanks Martin.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the last several years `getRectsBeingDrawn` returns the unified rectangle rather than the individual ones.